# error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to put together an extremely basic iPad 1 app to use with young students that I thought I could pull together pretty easily, but I am stuck.  I just want the user to be able to choose a name from a segmented control list, hit the GO button, and view that teacher's personal webpage.  That's it. 3 actions.

I get this error and for the life of me I can't troubleshoot it.  I apologize in advance about my mega mega newbiness when it comes to coding and Obj-C.  I have read a thousand Q&A's for similar issue, but none really addresses my problem because every code aims for something totally different.

I hope I am explaining my issue properly, and any help at all is most appreciated.  Here's a snippet with changed names, and in CAPITALS is the line where the error occurs:

```
@synthesize nameChoice;
@synthesize teacherView;

-(IBAction)getTeacher:(id)sender {
    NSURL *pageURL;
    NSString *pageURLString;
    NSString *name;
    int nameNum;

    name=[nameChoice titleForSegmentAtIndex:
            nameChoice.selectedSegmentIndex];

    pageURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
        @"http://teacher.website.com/home/showrandomipad.php?name=%@&session=%d"
        ,name,nameNum];

    pageURL=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pageURLString];

    [teacherView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pageURL]];

    [pageURLString release];
    [pageURL release];
}

{       HERE IS THE ERROR (error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token)
    (switch)nameNum {
        case 0:
            name=@"Teacher 1";
            nameVal=@"teacher 1";
            break;
        case 1:
            name=@"Teacher 2";
            nameVal=@"teacher 2";
            break;
        case 2:



        //the list of teachers goes from here.... etc etc etc
```

Comment: can you edit the code part format? it kind if messy and hard to see where it starts/edns...

Answer (score 5):

You are closing the method after `[pageURL release];` and then adding a new `{` to start the switch statement (which is also in a very weird format)

Did you intend to create a new method there? If so you should pay attention to the correct method's syntax.

You can check this docs for the method syntax:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html

And this for the C switch statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

change:

```
(switch)nameNum
```

to:

```
switch (nameNum)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I ended up deleting the project and starting from scratch.  It turns out I had some unnecessary code still hanging around from a function I had removed, and that was locking me up.